# Reload the previous page by clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

My main page look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="MainPage" data-role="page">
        <script>
            $("#MainPage").live("pageinit", function () { ... });
        </script>
        ...//I have a map and when I walk to the next page I delete the map.
    </div>
</body>
```

My next page look like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="NextPage" data-role="page">
    <script>
      $("#NextPage").live("pageinit", function () {... });
    </script>
 <a data-res="btnBack" data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="MainPage.html"
                data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" onclick="document.MainPage.reload(true);">
            </a>
    ...//I have a map and when I walk to the Main page I delete the map.
  </div>
</body>
```

Because I delete the maps I have to reload the main page and it does not work that way, the main page is not recognized as a page and therefore has no reload function.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The main page is not recognized as a page, I tested it in console window, I think that's the problem! 
does anyone know why he is not recognized as a page? 
I wrote : data-role = "page" to the div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to save the web address of the main page when you go from main page to next page.

for example :
 you use a link or button to traverse from one page to other use this code to save the url of the current page and then send it to other page using querystring or something else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url =$(location).attr("href");
});
```

variable 'url' contains the url of main page , now reload function to reload it. as:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 window.reload(url);
 })
```

Comment: Window object has no method 'reload', it did not work that way so I wrote it in the console, and got the following error:
TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'reload'

Comment: It works!!
By clicking the Back button, I read to a function that executes the command: window.loction.herf=url;
Thank you :]

Answer (score 0):

To jump to any other page use this code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page", {transition: "none", reloadPage : false});
```

Set a transition effect if you want one, and set reloadPage true if you want to reload that page.

Use this code to reload current page:

```
function refreshPage() {
  $.mobile.changePage(
    window.location.href,
    {
      allowSamePageTransition : true,
      transition              : 'none',
      showLoadMsg             : false,
      reloadPage              : true
    }
 );
```

}

Comment: $.mobile.changePage("#MainPage", { transition: "none", reloadPage: true });- its refresh the current page not the main